Reminder: we have a chat
This is not a question but just a reminder that we have a site-wide chat which is currently somewhat underused.

Do you have a question but not sure if it's on-topic or how to formulate it properly to get good answers?
Do you want to share some new exciting development in the RE field?
Do you want to discuss an interesting question you saw on the site, or have some thoughts about running the site not quite fleshed out for a meta post?
Do you want just to chat with people with similar interests?

Come over to our general chat room!
NOTE: you need to have at least 20 reputation to join the chat.
If you forget the direct link, you can also reach it by going to https://chat.stackexchange.com/ while logged in or find it via the SE site switcher menu:

Feel free to discuss the chat in replies (or in the room).
